# Difference in Difference with multiple time periods

Tags: difference-in-difference

I am not sure how to overcome the serial correlation issue that arises when I make a time dummy variable, $D_t$.

I am trying to do a Difference-in-Difference regression as below:

$y_{it}=S_i+T_t + \beta (X_i \cdot D_t)+ \varepsilon_{it} $

, subscript $i$ is industrial sectors (twenty sectors), and $t$ is month. $S_i$ is industry fixed effect, $T_t$ is time fixed effect, and $D_t=0$ if 2020m1, m2, and m3; $D_t=1$ if 2021m1, m2, and m3. $X_i$ is continuous and time invariant. It is a treatment intensity.

I am wondering if the above model is even possible or not: it is similar that each sector is triple duplicated. It is likely that m1, m2, and m3 are serially correlated. If I assume errors' strict exogeneity, then time fixed effect, $T_t$, may have already solved the serial-correlation issue. Maybe not. I would like to ask for your answer about this issue. And if this is really an issue, is there a solution? Should I avoid using consecutive months like this?

[image]

Comment: What's happening to the data from the other 9 months? Are you clustering your standard errors in any way?

Comment: The other 9 months are dropped. What should I cluster by? Cluster by time or industry?

Comment: Dropping data seems like an odd choice to me. You should cluster by industry for sure. Clustering on time as well would make sense if you expect there to be simultaneous shocks that are arbitrarily correlated across multiple industries. So a shock that hits all industries at time t will get picked up by the time fixed effect, but you need time clustering to handle events like if 2 industries use inputs produced by a third, which experiences a shock to its input prices. Time FEs cannot really handle that sort of thing easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I am trying as you suggested.

Comment: Why did you drop the periods before industrial sectors enter into treatment?

Comment: Right after D=0 period, the actual treatment begins. However, in this period (the dropped period), there is a production shock. So the dependent variable is confounded by this production shock. As a result, the treatment effect is not well explained if I do not exclude this period.